# C# convert any format string to double

Tags: c#, string, format, double, type-conversion

I tried searching google and stackoverflow without success.

I'm having a problem with "Input string was not in a correct format." exception with an application I'm working at.

Thing is, that I convert some double values to strings with doubleNumber.ToString("N2"); in order to store them in XML file. When I switch testing machines, XML file stored on one can't be returned back to double values.

I've tried all of the solutions I could think of, but setting number culture didn't work, using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, replacing characters also doesn't work. Sometimes the values are stored like "3,001,435.57" and sometimes (on other PC) like "3.001.435,57".

Is there some function or a way to parse a double from string, whatever the input format is?

Thanks.

Comment: You must have messed up your use of InvariantCulture somewhere. It should work on any PC with consistent number separators and decimal poitns.

Comment: @jv42 As I said in another comment, it can be saved in one culture and read in another, so the culture isn't consistent over PC's where the app can be used.

Comment: I must have misunderstood some part. If you are creating the files, you can specify the culture when *saving* (Invariant) to be the same when *loading* (Invariant too), so it wouldn't differ from machine to machine.

Comment: @jv42 Will try to recheck my code, to see if I'm missing the use of culture somewhere. Convert.toDouble gave me some bad results, so I might have badly replaced it somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify a culture because (eg.) "3,001" is ambiguous - is it 3.001 or 3001?

Depending on what your numbers look like, perhaps you could attempt to detect the culture by counting number of `,` and `.` characters and/or checking their positions.

Comment: Something like that is what I'm searching for... Counting the number of characters wouldn't work, since number can have only one of each.
Only thing that could work is checking the position for decimal separator, but that could also be tricky, since the number can be longer or shorter behind the decimal point (eg. 301.108).

Comment: How about using TryParse for a culture, move on to the next common culture if failed, rinse and repeat?

Comment: @Martheen That might work, I thought that someone might have a simpler solution. Work out the cultures, and try until one works doesn't sound like an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s9ak971.aspx

This will accept a string variable and a format provider.  You need to create a format provider that provides the culture information you are looking to convert out of.

Comment: The thing is that I don't know the culture, since application can be used in multiple cultures. So I need the way to detect the culture from the string, and not from the system it's run at. (Numbers can be saved in one culture format, and read in another culture)

Comment: you would get the Culture from the Environment static class.